# Using Average Function together with JOIN functions in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, average

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I just cannot figure out how to implement the code for extracting an AVERAGE from a column from a particular table. Grateful if anyone can help pointing out what is wrong with my enclosed codes.

As you can see, I am joining columns from different tables to get my expected output. It is the AVERAGE part that is giving me headaches! The Column is called "RoomRate" (andI need the Average of that Amount grouped by the ReservationID) and the table from which I need get it is called "ReservationStayDate".

Thanks for your help!

```
USE MY_DATABASE
SELECT a.ReservationStayID,
       a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS 'Name',
       b.PropertyCode AS'Property',
       b.ReservationStatus,
       b.MarketSegmentCode,
       a.ArrivalDate,
       a.DepartureDate,
       c.AdultCount,
       c.ChildCount,
       b.GuestCount,
       c.TaProfileID,
       c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
       c.CurrencyCode,
       d.rsl_nationality,
       d.rsl_country AS 'Cty of   Residence',
       d.rsl_totalroomrate,
       e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
       e.CountryCode AS 'Market',
       f.[RateAmount]
FROM GuestNameInfo a
JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID
JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID
JOIN
  (SELECT avg(RateAmount) AS 'RateAmount'
   FROM ReservationStayDate
   GROUP BY ReservationStayID) ReservationStayDate f ON f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID
```

Comment: It's the last "JOIN" function that is posing me problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ReservationStayID in the sub-selects select-list.

Also multiply RateAmount with 1.0 if its an integer column.

Answer (score 0):

your sql should look something like this

```
USE MY_DATABASE

SELECT a.ReservationStayID,
       a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS 'Name',
       b.PropertyCode AS'Property',
       b.ReservationStatus,
       b.MarketSegmentCode,
       a.ArrivalDate,
       a.DepartureDate,
       c.AdultCount,
       c.ChildCount,
       b.GuestCount,
       c.TaProfileID,
       c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
       c.CurrencyCode,
       d.rsl_nationality,
       d.rsl_country AS 'Cty of   Residence',
       d.rsl_totalroomrate,
       e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
       e.CountryCode AS 'Market',
       f.[RateAmount],

 (SELECT avg(RateAmount)
   FROM ReservationStayDate f
   where f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID ) as RateAmount

FROM GuestNameInfo a
     JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
     JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
     JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID
     JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID
```

Comment: Thanks Gary but I get the following message when running the codes:
"The multi-part identifier "f.RateAmount" could not be bound."

Comment: drop the f.[RateAmount]  column from the select statement, the column right after that should return the value you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Gary...works like a charm! I added the following code to the Query by using the logic of your answer but it is is giving errors..any ideas?
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day,rsl_departuredate,rsl_arrivaldate)-1
      FROM P5RESERVATIONLIST g
      WHERE g.rsl_code = a.ReservationStayID ) as 'Nights'

Comment: What is the error? I notice that you alias the table P5RESERVATIONLIST with the letter g but you don't use it in the select part of the query, you probably should. As soon as you select from more than one table you should always fully qualify the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OVER` clause as it's more efficient than using subqueries to derive the aggregate values.

```
USE MY_DATABASE
SELECT a.ReservationStayID,
       a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS 'Name',
       b.PropertyCode AS'Property',
       b.ReservationStatus,
       b.MarketSegmentCode,
       a.ArrivalDate,
       a.DepartureDate,
       c.AdultCount,
       c.ChildCount,
       b.GuestCount,
       c.TaProfileID,
       c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
       c.CurrencyCode,
       d.rsl_nationality,
       d.rsl_country AS 'Cty of   Residence',
       d.rsl_totalroomrate,
       e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
       e.CountryCode AS 'Market',
       --Aggregate function with Over clause
       AVG(f.RateAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY a.ReservationStayID) AS RateAmount
FROM GuestNameInfo a
JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID
JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID
JOIN ReservationStayDate f ON f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID
```